# Can I stop the default double click behaviour on a Eclipse Git Explorer Repository branch or tag?

Tags: eclipse, egit

I use Git Explorer Repository to review my branches and tagged commits inside of Eclipse. These are all shown in a tree view on the left side of the perspective.

On a couple of occasions I've found myself accidentally double clicking on a branch / tag and suffering as the EGit checks out my working directory which can takes minutes in some cases and trigger unwanted auto builds. And then more minutes to get back to where I was.

Is there a way to customize the Git Repo Explorer to disable the default double click action to prevent these inadvertent mistakes?

Comment: Maybe you should change the O.S. double-click threshold?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to change the double-click action. Maybe we could consider showing a confirmation dialog in case the user invoked the action using a double-click. Please [file an enhancement request for EGit](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EGit&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All).

Comment: I've raised a bug on it, but it's a major UI issue IMO

Comment: Here's the bug report, so that others can follow it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417971